# Cannot connect to apache server locally

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, netcat

I am trying to access an Apache server on my local machine, but can't get it to work. I had it working last week, but then it randomly stopped working. I have edited the httpd.conf file to update the port to 9876. I also added the ExecCGI directive in the HTDocs directory.

I usually see the index.html page I created by visiting localhost:9876, but now I just see an erroneous page. When I just run localhost:80, I see the it works page! How is something still showing up on port 80 when I clearly changed it to another port? I read more about this and found out it has to do with the sharing settings on OSX. These settings were never enabled to begin with. Why am I still seeing a page on port 80, and why is the designated port I chose not showing any content?

Things I have done:

1. I have tried stopping and restarting the server multiple times(with
   sudo)
2. I use the web browser or netcat to connect to apache, but I get no response.

I ran lsof -i4TCP:9876 and get the following output:

```
launchd      1           root   25u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f1b6f      0t0    TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
launchd      1           root   26u  IPv4 0xee69429dde6f2b77      0t0    TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
LogMeIn     82           root    5u  IPv4 0xee69429dde6f238f      0t0    TCP *:globe (LISTEN)
vpnagentd   83           root    6u  IPv4 0xee69429de115bb77      0t0    TCP localhost:29754 (LISTEN)
GitHub     201  kamranpirwani    6u  IPv4 0xee69429de35f4b77      0t0    TCP localhost:25035 (LISTEN)
GitHub     201  kamranpirwani    7u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f0eaf      0t0    TCP localhost:25035 (LISTEN)
mysqld     412         _mysql   14u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6efdaf      0t0    TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani    5u  IPv4 0xee69429deb25fb77      0t0    TCP *:6942 (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani    7u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f12ef      0t0    TCP *:6942 (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani   10u  IPv4 0xee69429deb47438f      0t0    TCP *:50490 (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani   11u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f062f      0t0    TCP *:50490 (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani   12u  IPv4 0xee69429dea898b77      0t0    TCP *:50491 (LISTEN)
Coda\x202  726  kamranpirwani   13u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6ef96f      0t0    TCP *:50491 (LISTEN)
httpd     1879           root    5u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f172f      0t0    TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1880           _www    5u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f172f      0t0    TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1920           _www    5u  IPv6 0xee69429dde6f172f      0t0    TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

This leads me to believe the my apache web server is listening for requests on this port. Why can't the browser or netcat connect to it?

Edit:

Log file(with personal email removed) http://pastebin.com/84RcB2Er

Comment: I am running OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you say (emphasis mine):

> I am trying to access an Apache server on my **local machine**, but
>   can't get it to work.

But then you say (again, emphasis mine):

> When I just run on **localhost**, I see the it works page!

So unclear what the problem is.When you say you edited the `.conf` which one?  Apache by default can handle virtual hosts so it’s possible you are running two virtual hosts on your machine with different document roots: One responding on port `80` & the other on port `9876`.  Can you exact details of the contents of the file you changed?

**EDIT:** The original poster indicates they are editing the `httpd.conf` in this location:

```
~/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

When the systemwide Apache config is in this location:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. If I run just 'localhost' I see the "It work's page!" However, when I run it on the desired port(9876) nothing happens. The index.html page does not load. I simply changed the Listen to 9876 int he .conf file. You can find it attached in my post

Comment: The only problems I have with switching now is that I previously had everything working. This just randomly stopped working. The conf file I am referring to resides in ~/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: I just erased the apache directory I had and used the /etc/apache2 one. Thanks.